# How to block duplicate fields on tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I tried load an array from web service and display on tableview, But I have a problem.

I dont want display duplicate fields on tableview.

I want display only one field on table.

Now I have :

1234

1235

1234

6544

2234

6544

e.g 1234 and 6544 have duplicate

Load Array Code :

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes: (NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchID"] )
    {
        teveRetorno = YES;
    }
    else if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"GetBranchResult"] )
    {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (teveRetorno)
    {
        [myArray addObject:string];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BranchID"] )
    {
        [[self tableView]reloadData];
    }

    teveRetorno = NO;
}
```

Table Code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.myArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text =[myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with a tableview. It's totaly the job of the datasource. You should filter the array for duplicates before you reload the tableview.

Comment: Convert your NSArray to an NSOrderedSet and you are done with the duplicates

Comment: If u want good answer that ask good question at least remove unwanted space from code.

Comment: @CRDave Ok thank you.I will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not to do anything with tableView. 
You might want to use something like this

```
if(![array containsObject:Value])
 {
    //add object to array.
}
```

if condition is true then only add value otherwise don't add it.

Comment: this should work fine I guess. But i am not sure why its not working for you. Where did u put this code ?

Comment: I used after add object to array.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the duplicates from the array you're using to populate the table. This can be done with:

```
NSOrderedSet *distinctItems = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:self.myArray];
self.myArray = [distinctItems array];
```

Do this after you populate `myArray` from your data load and before you reload the table view.

Comment: I added this code and result is here http://pastie.org/8059195 It give  error when running

Answer (score 0):

Deal with your datasource array.Remove the duplicate entries.Then Load data via `reloadData`